# 400 thrown when sub called from different sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I'm getting a very strange 400 error that I cannot explain.

I have two sheets

1. `Reconciliation Reporting` (Button pointing to a Sub "ThisWorkbook.ImportRawData"
2. `Trading Day Processes`, on which the import is actually happening also with a button pointing to "ThisWorkbook.ImportRawData"

When I click the button in Sheet `Trading Day Processes` everything works without a problem. When the button is clicked in Sheet `Reconciliation Reporting` then a 400 appears.

I have traced the error down. When I comment the part out everything works. I cannot find the reason for this 400 error, that the following part could cause.

```
tradingDaySheet.Range(Cells(lastRow, 1), Cells(lastRow, 70)).Borders(xlEdgeTop).LineStyle = xlContinuous
tradingDaySheet.Range(Cells(lastRow, 1), Cells(lastRow, 70)).Borders(xlEdgeTop).Weight = xlThick
tradingDaySheet.Range(Cells(lastRow, 1), Cells(lastRow, 70)).Borders(xlEdgeBottom).LineStyle = xlContinuous
tradingDaySheet.Range(Cells(lastRow, 1), Cells(lastRow, 70)).Borders(xlEdgeBottom).Weight = xlThick
tradingDaySheet.Range(Cells(lastRow, 1), Cells(lastRow, 70)).Borders(xlEdgeLeft).LineStyle = xlContinuous
tradingDaySheet.Range(Cells(lastRow, 1), Cells(lastRow, 70)).Borders(xlEdgeLeft).Weight = xlThick
tradingDaySheet.Range(Cells(lastRow, 1), Cells(lastRow, 70)).Borders(xlEdgeRight).LineStyle = xlContinuous
tradingDaySheet.Range(Cells(lastRow, 1), Cells(lastRow, 70)).Borders(xlEdgeRight).Weight = xlThick
```

The `ImportRawData` sub (I have cut out the code that is not relevant for this error.

```
Sub ImportRawData()
' main function to importing from _data into Trading Day Processes
    Dim Workbook As Workbook
    Set Workbook = ThisWorkbook
    Set tradingDaySheet = Workbook.Worksheets("Trading Day Processes")

    ' variable needed for importing data
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim m As Integer
    Dim TDcurrentRow As Long
    Dim DAnumDataRows As Integer
    Dim MANnumDataRows As Integer
    Dim TDstartRow As Long
    Dim TDendRow As Integer
    Dim currentDatai As Integer
    ' variable to check if a row was importet successfully
    Dim importStatus As Boolean

    ' set the starting row in the Trading Day Processes Sheet
    TDstartRow = 11
    TDcurrentRow = TDstartRow
    ' get the amount of rows to import
    DAnumDataRows = CountDataRows
    ' set the end row
    TDendRow = TDstartRow + DAnumDataRows

    ' get the mount of rows for manual entries
    MANnumDataRows = CountManualRows



    ' check if the sheet is clean otherwise throw message
    If IsEmpty(tradingDaySheet.Range("C11").Value) = True Then

         ' Import Automatic processes
        For i = 1 To DAnumDataRows
            importStatus = ImportNextRow(i, TDcurrentRow, False)
            TDcurrentRow = TDcurrentRow + 1
        Next i

        ' Import Manual processes
        For m = 1 To MANnumDataRows

            importStatus = ImportNextRow(m, TDcurrentRow, True)
            TDcurrentRow = TDcurrentRow + 1
        Next m

        ' Create End of Day Balance
        CreateEndOfDayRow (TDcurrentRow)

        ' Create P&L Sheet
        'CreatePandLReporting (TDstartRow,TDcurrentRow)

    Else
        MsgBox "The _data sheet has not been cleared. Please clean the sheet first."
    End If
    MsgBox "Import Done. Happy reconciling"

End Sub
```

The Sub calls a function CreateEndOfDayRow(). I have cut out some code that is not relevant for this error (too long otherwise):

```
Function CreateEndOfDayRow(lastRow As Long)
' The function creates the end of day balance after all intraday processes have been imported
    Dim Workbook As Workbook
    Set Workbook = ThisWorkbook
    Set dataSheet = Workbook.Worksheets("_data")
    Set tradingDaySheet = Workbook.Worksheets("Trading Day Processes")
    Dim startRow As Integer
    Dim startRowIncStartBalance As Integer
    Dim rowDiff As Integer
    startRowIncStartBalance = 10
    startRow = 11

    ' calc difference between first and last row for automatic formulas
    rowDiff = lastRow - startRow
    rowDiffIncStartBalance = lastRow - startRowIncStartBalance

    tradingDaySheet.Cells(lastRow, 1).Value = "EOD Balance"

    tradingDaySheet.Cells(lastRow, 70).NumberFormat = FormattingModule.FormatHelper("Percentage")


    ===== CUT OUT CODE =======

      ====>The following lines seem to cause the error

     ' put fat boarder around balances
     tradingDaySheet.Range(Cells(lastRow, 1), Cells(lastRow, 70)).Borders(xlEdgeTop).LineStyle = xlContinuous
     tradingDaySheet.Range(Cells(lastRow, 1), Cells(lastRow, 70)).Borders(xlEdgeTop).Weight = xlThick
     tradingDaySheet.Range(Cells(lastRow, 1), Cells(lastRow, 70)).Borders(xlEdgeBottom).LineStyle = xlContinuous
     tradingDaySheet.Range(Cells(lastRow, 1), Cells(lastRow, 70)).Borders(xlEdgeBottom).Weight = xlThick
     tradingDaySheet.Range(Cells(lastRow, 1), Cells(lastRow, 70)).Borders(xlEdgeLeft).LineStyle = xlContinuous
     tradingDaySheet.Range(Cells(lastRow, 1), Cells(lastRow, 70)).Borders(xlEdgeLeft).Weight = xlThick
     tradingDaySheet.Range(Cells(lastRow, 1), Cells(lastRow, 70)).Borders(xlEdgeRight).LineStyle = xlContinuous
     tradingDaySheet.Range(Cells(lastRow, 1), Cells(lastRow, 70)).Borders(xlEdgeRight).Weight = xlThick

     SetLastRow (lastRow)

End Function
```

Maybe it has to do with the wrong use of Worksheets? As explained above when the Sub is called from within the same sheet everything works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

most probably its due to the fact that with

```
tradingDaySheet.Range(Cells(lastRow, 1), Cells(lastRow, 70))....
```

all those `Cells` `Range` references are *implicitly* qualified with `ActiveSheet` as sheet reference, while you need it to be `tradingDaySheet`

so the solution would be using *explicit* `Worksheet` reference in your `Range` object

```
tradingDaySheet.Range(tradingDaySheet.Cells(lastRow, 1), tradingDaySheet.Cells(lastRow, 70))....
```

and so on

a more elegant (and less verbose) way to do that is by means of `With ... End With` syntax:

```
With tradingDaySheet ' reference wanted sheet object
    .Range(.Cells(lastRow, 1), .Cells(lastRow, 70)).... ' all object references beginning with a dot (`.`) are implicitly referencing the object in the `With` statement
    ....
End With
```

which could be pushed further to:

```
With tradingDaySheet ' reference wanted sheet object
    With .Range(.Cells(LastRow, 1), .Cells(LastRow, 70)) ' reference referenced sheet Range object
        .Borders(xlEdgeTop).LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .Borders(xlEdgeTop).Weight = xlThick
        .Borders(xlEdgeBottom).LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .Borders(xlEdgeBottom).Weight = xlThick
        .Borders(xlEdgeLeft).LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .Borders(xlEdgeLeft).Weight = xlThick
        .Borders(xlEdgeRight).LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .Borders(xlEdgeRight).Weight = xlThick
    End With
End With
```

Comment: thanks that was the mistake. Added `tradingDaySheet.` before every Cells